# Error "library not found for lswiftXCTest" when I try to run the tests

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, quick-nimble

Get next error when I try to run the tests:

[image]

**How I tried to solve the problem?**

1. The simplest

Build -> Clean Build Folder

2. Next, I tried the following:

> ```
> sudo gem install cocoapods
> pod install
> ```

But can't get next warnings:

[image]

3. Next commands:

> ```
> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
> arch -x86_64 pod install
> ```

[image]

4. Also here is my Build settings of spec

[image]

**Q:** How can I solve the problem with Nimble?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?